# To Change the Jquery version of a ASP.NET App

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Currently I need to change the jquery version from 2 to 3 of an ASP.NET that is running on an IIS Server.

A vulnerability scanned our server and it created a incident to solve.

I found the file "<IIS_Directory>/Views/Index.cshtml" that has the Javascript references.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")
```

When I access from a browser I get several scripts instead of '  @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")'

How do I change the result of the '@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")' in a production environment?

**Constraints**
I Only have the publish folder.
At the moment I don't have the code source. until I have the code source I have to apply a patch.

Comment: The code you found bundles multiple javascript files. You could try overwriting the jquery files (usually in the scripts folder), but there is a chance you will break your application.

Comment: Moving between major versions (i.e. from 2 to 3) of anything is likely to break a few things and is unlikely to be a drop in replacement, this is why there is a major version change (usually). Are there other scripts that depend on version 2, are you going to have to update these too. The only way to do this reliably is to do it locally in a proper dev environment with the full source code and do proper testing before releasing to production.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this without source code.
The JQuery library is imported into the BundleConfig.
I think it may be a solution, although not optimal, replace under Scripts JQuery's files with  same file of version 3 and give it the same names.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")
```

Is used to render a script tag (you said there was more than 1 so the bundler must be in debug mode) but the configuration of that bundle will be done in .NET code so you cannot realistically change that without the source code.

Perhaps you could update the actual jQuery source files (using the same file name) on the server and you may get lucky that nothing being used by the other scripts uses anything that has been removed in the move to version 3.

The only way to do it properly and not risk breaking the site is to do it in a proper development environment with the full source code and a proper regression test of all of the sites features.